# Minio/S3 scenarios where files have to be moved in batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-storage, minio

I searched but haven't found a satisfying solution.

Minio/S3 does not have directories, only keys (with prefixes). So far so good.

Now I am in the need to change those prefixes. Not for a single file but for a whole bunch (a lot) files which can be really large (actually no limit).

Unfortunatly these storage servers seem not to have a concept of (and does not support):

- rename file
- move file

What has to be done is for each file

- copy the file to the new target location
- delete the file from the old source location

My given design looks like:

- users upload files to bucketname/uploads/filename.ext
- a background process takes the uploaded files, generates some more files and uploads them to bucketname/temp/filename.ext
- when all processings are done the uploaded file and the processed files are moved to bucketname/processed/jobid/new-filenames...

The path prefix is used when handling the object created notification to differentiate if it is a upload (start processing), temp (check if all files are uploaded) and processed/jobid for holding them until the user deletes them.

Imagine a task where 1000 files have to get to a new location (within the same bucket) copy and delete them one by one has a lot of space for errors. Out of storage space during the copy operation and connection errors without any chance for rollback(s). It doesn't get easier if the locations would be different bucktes.

So, having this old design and not chance to rename/move a file:

Is there any change to copy the files without creating new physical files (without duplicating used storage space)?

Any experienced cloud developer could give me please a hint how to do this bulk copy with rollbacks in error cases?

Anyone implemented something like that with a functional rollback mechanism if e.g. file 517 of 1000 fails? Copy and delete them back seems not to be way to go.

Currently I am using Minio server and Minio dotnet library. But since they are compatible with Amazon S3 this scenario could also have happend on Amazon S3.